# How to make this square with the following style

Tags: css

I need to create this style in CSS but I could not. The only thing that comes out is a square and I'm already pretty frustrated. I am new to css, I would appreciate it if you help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JovxO.png

Thanks!

I was trying to do it with before and after but it does not work

```
.rectangle:before {
  right: 10%;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  border-left: 100x solid;
}

.rectangle:after {
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid;
}
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly. These two CSS snippets on their own make little sense.

Comment: @04FS OK, the css fragments are really not useful. So I've deleted them, thanks!

Comment: There's lots of [useful resources](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/) for this out on the interwebs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#div {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
#div:before {
  border-top: 35px solid red;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  width: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybcr5qat/)

I looked at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/) for a list of shapes and found something similar to what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was what I wanted. One last question, if I need to put it inverted as in the image, how could I do it?

Comment: @camlefista I just changed my answer to what you're looking for.

Comment: You are very kind, now I learned how to do this, since it was costing me! Thank you again @Bodrov

Comment: worth to note that it's copied from here : https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/

Comment: so better give credit to them to avoid being seen as plagiarism which isn't allowed here

Comment: @TemaniAfif You're absolutely right. I updated my answer and stated that I used CSS tricks as a reference.